# When can a person be called rich?

Tags: definition

What is the common definition for economic richness of a person?
When can you say John Doe (hypothetical name) is rich (objectively)?

Strictly economically speaking, no philosophical debate.

Comment: Is Steve Job rich? But his wealth is not enough to bring a cure to his cancer.

Answer (score 3):

There is no commonly-accepted definition. Different countries and different organizations within a country will have different definitions.

For example, the African Development Bank [defines](https://www.afdb.org/fileadmin/uploads/afdb/Documents/Publications/The%20Middle%20of%20the%20Pyramid_The%20Middle%20of%20the%20Pyramid.pdf) the rich to be those with "per capita consumption levels" of >\$20 per day (2005 PPP).

That would be around or below the poverty line in most developed countries. For example, the [2018 US federal poverty line](https://www.healthcare.gov/glossary/federal-poverty-level-fpl/) for an individual is \$12,140 per annum or \$33.26 per day.

Comment: And even those are measures of income rather than wealth